# WAS ( Web Application Server ) migrate from 7.0.0 to 8.5.5

Tags: java, collections, ibm-was

In my compagny where i work, IT gouvernance have decided to migrate to WAS 8.5.5 with an JRE 1.7 for the JVM. I have two questions :

- We have an conflit on dependency which are injected in the classpath of the jvm. The library used by WAS isn't the same version than for my project. Biggest problem is that project have an dependency which works only with old version of common-beanutil.jar from apache, dependency couldn't be rebuild by my team for using the new version of common-beanutil.jar. 
  If I used old library i create many instability on WAS  8.5.5 and i lost the admin consol IHM. But if I used the last version of library, my dependency is broken and an important parts of my client cannot connect to the Website.

Can i limited the import of the old dependency to my project ? With the actual technical ( classpath ), i can't do this because i inject my dependency for the VM, if i clearly understood the system of classpath.

I see this topic on IBM :https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_classload.html

I am not sur that is the solution, if you confirm, i will investigate on this side.

- 2nd problem is the migration to JRE 7. We used in all the project List Object> ( Verryyy bad practical... ), the communication between Controller and DAO was based on an list object> pass throught the framework. Normaly Java supports the old technical, but i have strange behavior. List seems not be build on the same way between JRE 7 and JRE 6. In the DAO and in the controller wee access to the list by list.get(nummberOftheArgument). As we used object... i get sometimes CastException by java with JRE7, but it's seems random ! I read the oracle documentation on migration form JRE6 TO JRE7 but i didn't find information about an problem on List... Did you heard something about similar collection problem bewteen JRE 7 and JRE 6 with object ?

Thanks for your help! ( and sorry for my english, i am french ! )

Comment: You need to split this into two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to try putting your dependency that conflicts with WAS in an isolated shared library:

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-nd-dist&topic=trun_sharedlib

Comment: An isolated shared library is definitely the recommended practice.  See IBM TechNote: Best Practices for Integrating Open Source Software Frameworks with WebSphere Application Server at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21639407

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help about shareLibrary, i must admit that i haven't enough search before arriving on stackoverflow :s ! I will test this now.